# How to control version of records with referenced records (Foreign keys)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am developing an application and in which I have multiple tables,

```
Table Name : User_master
|Id (PK,AI) | Name | Email | Phone | Address

Table Name: User_auth
|Id (PK,AI) | user_id(FK_userMaster) | UserName | password | Active_Status

Table Name: Userbanking_details
|Id (PK,AI) | user_id(FK_userMaster) | Bank Name | account Name | IFSC
```

Now, what I want is to save all the updates done in records should not be updated directly instead it should control the version that means I want to track the log of all previous updates user has done.

Which means if user updates the address, then also previous address record history should be stored into the table.

I have tried it by adding fields version_name, version_latest, updated_version_of field and insert new record when update like

```
|Id (PK,AI) | Name | Email | Phone | Address |version_name |version_latest| updated_version_of
    1       | ABC  |ABC@gm.com|741852|LA     |1            |0             |1
    2       | ABC  |ABC@gm.com|852741|NY     |2            |1             |1
```

Now the problem comes here is the user table is in FK with other two listed tables so when updating the record their relationship will be lost because of new ID.

I want to preserve the old data shown as old and new updated records will be in effect only with new transactions.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how about enable CDC?

Comment: But how will i preserve referencing with new records?  i.e. the already referenced record in database which is mapped with bank, User_auth table using user_master's pk field.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your use case you can make a json field in your tables for storing the previous states or a new identical history table for each table.

Dump the entire hash into the history column everytime the user updates anything. 
Or insert a new row in the history table for each update in the original.

Comment: Yes it is a great suggestion yet the question remains unsolved to preserve referencing records. i.e. the already referenced record in database which is mapped with bank, User_auth table using user_master's pk field.

Answer (score 0):

Storing historical records and current records in the same table, is not a good practice, in a transactional system.

The reasons are:

1. There will be more I/O due to scanning more number of pages to identify a record
2. Additional maintenance effort on the table
3. Transactions getting bigger, longer and cause time out issues
4. Additional effort of cascading referential integrity changes to child tables

I would suggest to keep historical records in a separate table. You can have OUTPUT clause to have the historical records to be captured and inserted into separate table. In that way, your referential integrity will remain the same. In the historical table, you don't need to have PK defined.

A below sample for using OUTPUT clause with UPDATE. You can read more about OUTPUT clause [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements)

```
DECLARE @Updated table( [ID] int,
                        [Name_old] varchar(50),
                        [Email_old] varchar(50),
                        [Phone_old] varchar(50),
                        [Address_old] varchar(50),
                        [ModifiedDate_old] datetime);
Update User_Master
Set Email= 'NewEmail@Email.com', Name = 'newName', Phone='NewPhone', Address='NewAddress'
 ModifiedDate=Getdate()
OUTPUT deleted.Id as Id, deleted.Name as Name_old, deleted.Email as email_old ,
deleted.ModifiedDate as ModifiedDate_old, deleted.Phone as phone_old, deleted.Address AS Address_old, deleted.ModifiedDate as modifiedDate_old
INTO @updated
Where [Id]=1;
INSERT INTO User_Master_History
SELECT * FROM @updated;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have faced this situation in the past I have solved it in the following ways:

**First Method**

Recommended method.

Have a second table which acts as a change history. Because you are not adding rows to the main table your foreign keys maintain integrity.

There are now mechanisms in SQL Server to do this automatically.

[SQL Server 2016 Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017)
[SQL Server 2017 Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

**Second Method**

I don't recommend this as a good design, but it does work.

1. Treat one record as the primary record, and this record maintains a foreign key relationship with records in other related tables which are subject to change tracking.
2. Always update this primary record with any changes thereby maintaining integrity of the foreign keys.
3. Add a self-referencing key to this table e.g. `Parent` and a `date-of-change` column.
4. Each time the primary record is updated, store the old values into a new record in the same table, and set the `Parent` value to the `id` of the primary record. Again the primary record never changes, and therefore your foreign key relationships maintain integrity.
5. Using the `date-of-change` column in conjunction with the change history allows you to reconstruct the exact values at any point in time.

Comment: I have tried to do that as well, but in all cases my question remains unanswered, that is what for that previous transaction records. it means that suppose there is another table called order or other which will store the ordered items. 
Now when user orders item then address will be fetched from User_master table so if i update the record with separate table structure then the order table records history will go wrong. 

This is just a scenario, i can not store the address of user in order table. I have given scenario just for understanding purpose that i want to retain the history

Comment: @NiketNaik Sorry, but your problem is not quite clear yet (for me at least). Are you saying that if a customer has multiple orders (e.g. order 1 & order 2), and they change their address between order 1 and order 2, then order 1 needs to reference the address at the time order 1 was placed, and order 2 needs to reference the address at the time order 2 was placed i.e. each order needs to reference a different address record?

Comment: Im all with Dave for his first method. Could you elaborate more on the problem you have with this. Because I also find it not clear what the problem is here